# Create a new list of random items with a specific length in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of strings, when I click a button I want to generate a new list with a specific number of items from my original list of strings.

I'm able to generate a random list with no repeating items but the number of items that returns is random. For example I want a new list of 5 items, sometimes it returns with 2 items other times 4 etc.

```
var randomList = new List.generate(
            5, (_) => originalList[Random().nextInt(originalList.length)]).toSet().toList();
```

I've found lots of info for returning 1 random item, but nothing about multiples.

EDIT:

Thank you everyone for the responses, I was able to fix my problem by using shuffle like so

```
var randomList = (originalList..shuffle()).take(5).toList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method of getting random items out of the original list will result in duplicates, which are then eliminated when you call `.toSet()`, which is why you get lists of varying lengths.

Instead of calling `.toSet()` to prevent duplicates, we need to be sure that no duplicates are chosen in the first place.

One way of doing that would be to generate a list of numbers from `0` up to `originalList.length - 1`, then shuffle them, and then choose the first n numbers from that list, and map them to values from original list.

```
void main() {
  List<String> originalList = ["hello", "what", "goodbye", "Test", "Apple", "Banana"];

  List<int> indices = List<int>.generate(originalList.length, (i) => i);

  indices.shuffle();

  int newCount = 3;

  List<String> randomList = indices.take(newCount).map((i) => originalList[i]).toList();

  print(randomList);
}
```

This method is efficient, and has a worst case performance of O(n), assuming dart has an efficient `shuffle()` implementation (which I'm sure it does).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the list generates duplicates nonetheless.

```dart
var randomList = new List.generate(5, (_) => originalList[Random().nextInt(originalList.length)])
```

The list could contain `[dello, kello, hello, gello, hello]`
(for example, assume items are taken from the original list)

Now performing `.toSet()` on this will remove the duplicate `hello` from the list, this is what causes the list size to be random. In this instance it's two duplicates, but later on it could have more.

A simple solution for this would be

```dart
var randomList = [];

List.generate(5, (_) {
   var randomString = originalList[Random().nextInt(originalList.length)];

   while (randomList.contains(randomString)) {
      randomString = originalList[Random().nextInt(originalList.length)];
   }

   randomList.add(randomString);
});
```